# I cant figure out how to write an sql query to display the information how I want

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I've gotten my database set up for my website and I'm a little baffled on how I should write the SQL query to display the information how I want it.

Here's an image of how my database is setup and an example of how I want to display it:

[image]

Here's the SQL query I wrote to get the information (Im open to writing a better solution)

```
SELECT * FROM drinks_category, drinks_lookup, drinks
WHERE drinks.drink_id = drinks_lookup.drink_id
AND drinks_lookup.drinks_category_id = drinks_category.drinks_category_id
```

This gets me all the info but I'm not sure how to write the output to get it to show how i want.

Comment: is this school assignment ? This is a basic database query

Comment: Can a drink belong to more than one category? It doesn't happen in the data you posted, but do you want to allow that?

Comment: Do you need this as a pure SQL solution, or just to return each drink with the category they are in then use php for format it up to output it?

Comment: Also, did you write any query yet? Looks like all you need is two joins, an ordering by category.

Comment: Yes Karthikr, forgive my ignorance Im fairly new to this.

Comment: @Kickstart Thats exactly right! I've been able to write the SQL to get the information but cant figure out how to output it.

Comment: Could you show us the SQL you wrote then? The display logic depends on that.

Comment: @bfavaretto 'SELECT * FROM drinks_category, drinks_lookup, drinks WHERE drinks.drink_id = drinks_lookup.drink_id AND drinks_lookup.drinks_category_id = drinks_category.drinks_category_id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to order by category:

```
SELECT * 
FROM drinks_category, drinks_lookup, drinks 
WHERE drinks.drink_id = drinks_lookup.drink_id 
AND drinks_lookup.drinks_category_id = drinks_category.drinks_category_id
ORDER BY drinks_category.drink_category_title
```

With that, you can loop in PHP, and output a new header whenever a new category appears. Something like this:

```
<?php
$last_category = 0;
foreach($data as $row) {
    if($row['drinks_category_id'] != $last_category) {
        echo '<h1>' . $row['drink_category_title'] . '</h1>';
    }
    echo '<div>' . $row['drinks_name'] . '</div>';
    $last_category = $row['drinks_category_id'];
}
?>
```

You should probably use nested html lists instead of the markup above, but this should get you started.

Comment: Quick question, I've been trying to figure out a way to get this into a list and cant get it to work... could you help me get this working as a list? My main issue is trying to get the <ul> in there..

Comment: I you want a nested list, it can be a little tricky, and probably deserves a separate question. Nested or not, the outermost ul goes outside the loop.

Comment: Just wanted to give you an update on some answers I got for this http://stackoverflow.com/q/16755108/1837281 just in case you were interested.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, @AlbertFajardo. However what you asked for in that question is 3 separate lists (I thought you might want those 3 lists as list items of an outer list). I'm glad you got your answers anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Since you use PHP, the best way to do this is to use an outer-inner-query loop:

Outer query: `SELECT * FROM drings_category`, then loop:

- Display drink_category_title
- Use drink_category_id as $ID for `SELECT drinks.drink_name FROM drinks INNER JOIN drinks_lookup ON drinks.drink_id=drinks_lookup.drink_id WHERE drinks_lookup.drink_category_id=$ID`
- Loop and display drinks

Answer (score 0):

Hideously over complicated way to do it in a single sql statement for 3 fixed columns, coping with up to 1000 drinks in each category.

```
SELECT DrinkCategory1Subselect.drink_name AS 'Drink Category Title', DrinkCategory2Subselect.drink_name AS 'Drink Category Title 2', DrinkCategory3Subselect.drink_name AS 'Drink Category Title 3'
FROM (SELECT a.i+b.i*10+c.1*100 AS aCounter
FROM (SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) a,
(SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) b,
(SELECT 0 AS i UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) c) Deriv1
INNER JOIN (SELECT  c.drink_name, 
    @Counter := @Counter + 1 AS aCounter
FROM drinks_category a
INNER JOIN drinks_lookup b ON a.drink_category_id = b.drink_category_id
INNER JOIN drinks c ON b.drink_id = c.drink_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter:=0) NothingUseful
WHERE a.drink_category_id = 1
ORDER BY c.drink_id) DrinkCategory1Subselect
ON DrinkCategory1Subselect.aCounter = Deriv1.aCounter
INNER JOIN (SELECT  c.drink_name, 
    @Counter := @Counter + 1 AS aCounter
FROM drinks_category a
INNER JOIN drinks_lookup b ON a.drink_category_id = b.drink_category_id
INNER JOIN drinks c ON b.drink_id = c.drink_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter:=0) NothingUseful
WHERE a.drink_category_id = 2
ORDER BY c.drink_id) DrinkCategory2Subselect
ON DrinkCategory2Subselect.aCounter = Deriv1.aCounter
INNER JOIN (SELECT  c.drink_name, 
    @Counter := @Counter + 1 AS aCounter
FROM drinks_category a
INNER JOIN drinks_lookup b ON a.drink_category_id = b.drink_category_id
INNER JOIN drinks c ON b.drink_id = c.drink_id
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Counter:=0) NothingUseful
WHERE a.drink_category_id = 3
ORDER BY c.drink_id) DrinkCategory3Subselect
ON DrinkCategory3Subselect.aCounter = Deriv1.aCounter
WHERE DrinkCategory1Subselect.drink_name IS NOT NULL
OR DrinkCategory2Subselect.drink_name IS NOT NULL
OR DrinkCategory3Subselect.drink_name IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Deriv1.aCounter
```

Not tested. Better to do the formatting in php, but was bored