# How do I create a nested list inside of a while loop?

Tags: php, database, loops, mysqli

I'm having trouble trying to get a nested < ul > inside of a while loop. I'm not sure if this even possible so i'm open to alternatives.

[Here's a quick image of what my database looks like and what i'm trying to achieve.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPI2U.jpg)

Here's my sql

```
SELECT * 
FROM drinks_category, drinks_lookup, drinks 
WHERE drinks.drink_id = drinks_lookup.drink_id 
AND drinks_lookup.drinks_category_id = drinks_category.drinks_category_id
ORDER BY drinks_category.drinks_category_title
```

Here's my output php

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

$last_category = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if($row['drinks_category_id'] != $last_category) {
     echo "<h1>" . $row['drinks_category_title'] . "</h1>";
    }

    echo "<p>" . $row['drink_name'] . "</p>";
    $last_category = $row['drinks_category_id'];

}
```

Im using mysqli and php. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you really need the lookup table (the category_id could easily be stored in drinks table)? And personally I would solve this with 2 queries, one for the category, one for the drinks themselves (I don't know about the best practice in this case)

Comment: Can a drink have multiple categories? If it can't, then you don't need the junction table (the one that links Drinks to Categories).

Comment: Some drinks do fall under multiple categories. Thanks for the suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `while` loop to the following:

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

if($row['drinks_category_id'] != $last_category) {
 if($last_category != 0) echo '</ul>';
 echo "<h1>" . $row['drinks_category_title'] . "</h1>";
 echo "<ul>";
}

echo "<li>" . $row['drink_name'] . "</li>";
$last_category = $row['drinks_category_id'];

}
if($last_category != 0) echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: [The bottom of this image has the output I was hoping to get.](http://i.imgur.com/75u2cVf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having 3 tables, you could just add a category_id to your drinks table, just to simplify things. Then you can do this:

```
SELECT drink_name, (SELECT drnk_category_title FROM drinks_category WHERE drink_category_id = drink_category // THE COLUMN I SUGGESTED //) AS title FROM drinks
```

And then you can loop the result and build the nodes you desire really easily

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = $conn->query($sql) or die(mysqli_error());

$last_category = 0;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if($row['drinks_category_id'] != $last_category) {
        // close previous </ul>
        if( $last_category != 0 ) echo "</ul>";

        // new title
        echo "<h1>" . $row['drinks_category_title'] . "</h1>";

        // new <ul>
        echo "<ul>";

        $last_category = $row['drinks_category_id'];
    }

    echo "<li>" . $row['drink_name'] . "</li>";
}

// close last </ul>
if( $last_category != 0 ) echo "</ul>";
```