# how to list sub categories?

Tags: php, list, categories

Hi Everyone I am trying to lis subcats in the main categories like this:

`Maincat1

-subcat

Maincat2

-subcat`

Please see the 
[**image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulLEb.png)

This is the code listing main cats:

in the global_header.php

```
$sql_select_cats_list = $db->query("SELECT category_id, items_counter, hover_title, image_path FROM
            " . DB_PREFIX . "categories WHERE parent_id=0 AND hidden=0 AND user_id=0 AND enable_auctions=1 ORDER BY order_id ASC, name ASC");

    $template->set('sql_select_cats_list', $sql_select_cats_list);

    $category_box_content = $template->process('categories_box.tpl.php');
    $template->set('category_box_content', $category_box_content);
```

And this is the categories_box.tpl.php

```
<? 
while ($cats_header_details = $db->fetch_array($sql_select_cats_list)) 
{
    $category_link = process_link('categories', 
        array('category' => $category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']],
              'parent_id' => $cats_header_details['category_id']));
?>
   <li>
       <a style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration:none;"
          href="<?=$category_link;?>"
          <?=((!empty($cats_header_details['hover_title'])) ? 'title="' . $cats_header_details['hover_title'] . '"' : '');?>
          alt="">
              <img src="<?=$cats_header_details['image_path'];?>" width="10" height="8" border="0" />
              &nbsp;
              <?=$category_lang[$cats_header_details['category_id']];?>
              <?=(($setts['enable_cat_counters']) ?
                  (($cats_header_details['items_counter']) ?
                      '(<strong>' . $cats_header_details['items_counter'] . '</strong>)' :
                      '') :
                  '');
              ?>
        </a>
   </li>
<?
}
?>
```

Here is my original function listing categories on 
function.php

```
function category_navigator ($parent_id, $show_links = true, $show_category = true, $page_link = null, $additional_vars = null, $none_msg = null, $reverse_categories = false)
{
    global $reverse_categoy_lang, $category_lang, $db;

    (string) $display_output = NULL;
    (int) $counter = 0;

    $none_msg = ($none_msg) ? $none_msg : GMSG_ALL_CATEGORIES;

    $page_link = ($page_link) ? $page_link : $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    if($parent_id > 0)
    {
        $root_id = $parent_id;
        while ($root_id > 0)
        {
            $row_category = $db->get_sql_row("SELECT category_id, name, parent_id FROM 
                " . DB_PREFIX . (($reverse_categories) ? 'reverse_categories' : 'categories') . " WHERE 
                category_id=" . $root_id . " LIMIT 0,1");

            if($counter == 0)
            {
                $display_output = ($reverse_categories) ? $reverse_category_lang[$row_category['category_id']] : $category_lang[$row_category['category_id']];
                $display_output = (!empty($display_output)) ? $display_output : $row_category['name'];
            }
            else if($parent_id != $root_id)
            {
                $category_name = ($reverse_categories) ? $reverse_category_lang[$row_category['category_id']] : $category_lang[$row_category['category_id']];
                $category_name = (!empty($category_name)) ? $category_name : $row_category['name'];

                $display_output = (($show_links) ? '<a href="' . $page_link . '?parent_id=' . $row_category['category_id'] . '&name=' . sanitize_var($category_name) . ((!empty($additional_vars)) ? ('&' . $additional_vars) : '') . '">' : '') . $category_name . (($show_links) ? '</a>' : '') . ' > ' . $display_output;
            }
            $counter++;
            $root_id = $row_category['parent_id'];
        }
        $display_output = (($show_links && $show_category) ? '<a href="' . $page_link . '?' . $additional_vars . '"><b> ' . GMSG_CATEGORY . ':</b></a> ' : '') . $display_output;
    }

    $display_output = (empty($display_output)) ? $none_msg : $display_output;

    return $display_output;
}
```

Database name is : **categories**

```
table : categories  
    | category_id +   parent_id +        name         |
    | 1             |   0        |     Flower         |
    | 2             |   0        |     Wall Decor     |
    | 3             |   0        |     Stylish Living |
    | 4             |   1        |     Mug            |
    | 5             |   1        |     Sun Flower     |
```

I need help to do this please.
Nav menu

```
<div id="navigation">
        <ul> <li><a href="#">News</a>
                <ul> <li>National News</li> <li>International News</li> <li>Sports News </li> <li>Hollywood news</li> </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Technology</a>
                <ul> <li>IT/Software </li> <li>Hardware</li> <li>Iphone</li> <li>Neuro-Science</li> </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Sports</a>
                <ul> <li>Cricket</li> <li>Tenis</li> <li>Badminton</li> <li>Hockey</li> </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
            <a href="#">Contry</a>
                <ul> <li>India</li> <li>Shree lanka </li> <li>Bangaladesh</li> <li>England</li> </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Last modified:

Solved special thanks to @furas

Code:

```
 <div id="navigation">
            <ul>  <? 
       foreach($menu_multiarray as $main_category) 
        {
         $cats_link = process_link('categories', array('category' => $main_category['category']['name'], 'parent_id' => $main_category['category']['category_id']));
    ?>
    <li>
    <a style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration:none;" href="<?=$cats_link;?>" <?=((!empty($main_category['hover_title'])) ? 'title="' . $main_category['hover_title'] . '"' : '');?> alt="">
    <img src="<?=$main_category['image_path'];?>" width="10" height="8" border="0" />&nbsp;<?=$main_category['category']['name'];?>
             <?=(($setts['enable_cat_counters']) ? (($main_category['items_counter']) ? '(<strong>' . $main_category['items_counter'] . '</strong>)' : '') : '');?></a>
      <?  
        foreach($main_category["subcategories"] as $sub_category) 
        {
         $sub_cats_link = process_link('categories', array('category' => $sub_category['name'], 'parent_id' => $sub_category['category_id']));   
        ?>       
     <ul>
       <li>
       <a style="font-size: 11px; font-weight: normal; text-decoration:none;" href="<?=$sub_cats_link;?>" <?=((!empty($sub_category['hover_title'])) ? 'title="' . $sub_category['hover_title'] . '"' : '');?> alt="">
       <img src="<?=$sub_category['image_path'];?>" width="10" height="8" border="0" />&nbsp;<?=$sub_category['name'];?>
             <?=(($setts['enable_cat_counters']) ? (($sub_category['items_counter']) ? '(<strong>' . $sub_category['items_counter'] . '</strong>)' : '') : '');?></a>
        </li>
        </ul>
        <? } ?>
      </li>
       <? } ?>
    </ul>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pseudocode:

```
get_from_database_main_categories();

while( i_have_categories ) {
    print_category();
    get_from_database_subcategories_for_current_category();
    print_subcategories();
}
```

or maybe you can get all categories and subcategories in one SQL query and create menu in similar way to [How do I create a nested list inside of a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755108/how-do-i-create-a-nested-list-inside-of-a-while-loop)

**Edit:**

I don't give you full code but most of it.

Because you have code in two files I split my code into two parts - getting data and printing data

global_header.php (getting data)

```
function get_categories_by_parent($parent_id) 
{
    global $db;

    return $db->query(
                "SELECT category_id, items_counter, hover_title, image_path ".
                "FROM ".DB_PREFIX."categories ".
                "WHERE parent_id=".$parent_id." AND hidden=0 AND user_id=0 AND enable_auctions=1 ".
                "ORDER BY order_id ASC, name ASC"
            );
}

$categories = get_categories_by_parent(0);

$menu_multiarray = array();
$i = 0;

while ($main_category = $db->fetch_array($categories)) 
{
    $menu_multiarray[$i] = array();
    $menu_multiarray[$i]['category'] = $main_category;
    $menu_multiarray[$i]['subcategories'] = array();

    $subcategories = get_categories_by_parent($main_category['category_id']);

    while ($sub_category = $db->fetch_array($subcategories)) 
    {
        $menu_multiarray[$i]['subcategories'][] = $sub_category;
    }   

    $i++;
}

$template->set('menu_multiarray', $menu_multiarray);
```

categories_box.tpl.php (printing data)

```
foreach($menu_multiarray as $main_category) 
{
    // print main category using 
    // $main_category['category']['category_id']
    // $main_category['category']['items_counter']
    // $main_category['category']['hover_title']
    // $main_category['category']['image_path']

    $limit = 10;

    foreach($main_category['subcategories'] as $sub_category) 
    {
        // print sub category using 
        // $sub_category['category_id']
        // $sub_category['items_counter']
        // $sub_category['hover_title']
        // $sub_category['image_path']

        $limit--;
        if( $limit == 0 ) break; 
    }

    if( $limit > 0 ) echo "link to rest of subcategorie";
}
```

Of course I didn't test the code but it show you which way to go.

Comment: So kind of you, i'm not very good at php, if you can give full code to help me out i will be grateful to you.

Comment: Thanks furas, you are not a human:) an angel:) thanks again there is only one problem geting this error ? Fatal error: Call to a member function query() on a non-object in C:\AppServ\www\wor\global_header.php on line 93  LINE 93 IS:   return $db->query( Return empty why.

Comment: I see. I use `$db` inside function `get_categories_by_parent` but `$db` is declared outside. You have to add `global $db;` in first line in that function (like in your function `category_navigator`). I changed this in my code.

Comment: How can I set limit 10 for subcategories, and For the rest display ALL SUBCATEGORIES LINK

Comment: I add `$limit` in `categories_box.tpl.php` to limit subcategories.

Comment: Very poor no Reputation to do it:)

Answer (score 1):

You can do that without multiple queries.

```
SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY parent ASC, order_id ASC, name ASC
```

pseudocode:

```
while ($result = fetch_array()) {
  if ($result['parent'] == 0) {
    $categories[$result['category_id']] = $result;
  }
  else {
    $categories[$result['parent']]['categories'][$result['category_id']] = $result;
  }
}
```

This will add all categories with parent 0 directly to an array, all subcategories will be added to a subarray inside the parent. Ordering by parent will make sure that the parent categories are already there when they are needed.

This will only work for one level though, for more levels you would need to look through all existing categories in the array to find the right parent. But I think it will still be better than multiple SQL queries.

Comment: How can I set limit 10 for subcategories, and For the rest display ALL SUBCATEGORIES LINK

Comment: Version with one query is much better. I only mentioned about that possibility but didn't think how to do this.